# Your new site design is live!

Tags: discussion, design

As you can see, the new design just went live!

At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your [valuable design feedback](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/chess-site-design-and-logo-draft/) and for your patience while we got this out for you.

We really hope you like the design!

Comment: Congrats for the new design!

Answer (score 16):

Thanks very much, the site looks great IMHO.
Just one little thing: while the favicons looked great on the [feedback post](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1161/chess-site-design-and-logo-draft/)...

[image]

... at their actual size they just look like a sand/grey box with a smaller, darker box inside:

[image]

(Sorry for the blurry capture, I had to resize the image for it to match the actual screen size in my 13" MacBook Pro -- but trust me, the favicons look almost exactly the same.)

The white-rook-on-blue-field favicon didn't have this problem: it was clear that the central figure was a rook.

Does anybody else experience this? And if so, can something be done about it?

Comment: I was wondering what this site is with a cooking pot icon... It seems to be the only icon that's an image inside a box, which makes the queen a fraction of the size it could've been. If the whole icon were a queen, it may look much better, but that image probably still has way too much detail for an icon. I'd probably have gone for a bishop or pawn, since those have very distinctive and simple shapes.

Comment: Yep, I noticed this issue and pointed it out internally as well. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Coming here from [the sidebar HNQ list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk645.png). As I'm not familiar with most chess players, I had no clue what this question was about before visiting it...

Comment: @AndrewT. you ninja'd me ... I did know what the question would be about, but it was still hard to see whether it was posted on this site.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing this out! I agree, and I'll look at alternatives.

Comment: @Chloe dropping the speech balloon and enlarging the queen seems simplest to me - that's what happens with most sites, if you compare https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday with their HNQ icons.

Comment: @Glorfindel yes, that's what I'm thinking too. I've had covid so have been slow on this, but my goal is to get this done next week!

Comment: Thanks @Chloe, I hope you'll recover quickly :)

Comment: Thanks for your patience everyone—this has been updated!

Comment: @Chloe thanks and great job! [It's far better now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kvnk.png) :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Chloe! Much better indeed ^^

Comment: Very late to the comment here, but a little sad the discussion we had on logo all those years ago went nowhere - https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32/what-should-the-chessse-logo-be

Answer (score 8):

Thank you for the effort invested in engaging the community and implementing the new site design.

All the little details really come together very well.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all so very much. To many years more of chess galore! We shall see how everyone likes it. Strange for a sudden change, in a way, after so many years of silent blue.

Comment: Your subsequent post relevant to the new design: [Option to have our screen blue, but retain the new design?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1181/29692)

Answer (score -4):

I am not personally a big fan. The site now feels very dark and crowded. But, I can see that everyone else likes it, so Ill drop that. Still excited that we have our logo and banner.